# JavaScript if/else if/else statement is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is my if/else if/ else statement:

```
var shirtWidth = 18;
var shirtLength = 33;
var shirtSleeve = 8.63;

// Small Shirts
if(shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth < 20) {
        if(shirtLength >= 28 && shirtLength < 29)
        if(shirtSleeve >= 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38) {
            console.log("S");
        }
}
// Medium Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 20 && shirtWidth < 22) {
        if(shirtLength >= 29 && shirtLength < 30)
        if(shirtSleeve >= 8.38 && shirtSleeve < 8.63) {
            console.log("M");
        }
}
// Large Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 22 && shirtWidth < 24) {
        if(shirtLength >= 30 && shirtLength < 31)
        if(shirtSleeve >= 8.63 && shirtSleeve < 8.88) {
            console.log("L");
        }
}
// XL Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 24 && shirtWidth < 26) {
        if(shirtLength >= 31 && shirtLength < 33)
        if(shirtSleeve >= 8.88 && shirtSleeve < 9.63) {
            console.log("XL");
        }
}
// 2XL Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 26 && shirtWidth < 28) {
        if(shirtLength >= 33 && shirtLength < 34)
        if(shirtSleeve >= 9.63 && shirtSleeve < 10.13) {
            console.log("2XL");
        }
}
// 3XL Shirts
else if(shirtWidth === 28) {
        if(shirtLength === 34)
        if(shirtSleeve === 10.13) {
            console.log("3XL");
        }
}
// Does not match any shirt sizes
else {
    console.log("N/A");
}
```

Everything works except when I get to the else statement at the end. It only works for numbers greater than the 3XL shirts. However, if the numbers are combination of measurements from the 6 categories, the else statement does not print. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This should be a `switch` to make it so much simpler.

Comment: And I'd ***strongly*** recommend not using actively misleading indentation on those inner stacked `if`s. (And always using braces, rather than leaving them out sometimes.) No reason for stacking those inner `if`s, either; us `&&`.

Comment: *It only works for numbers greater than the 3XL shirts* - well yes; all other eventualities are captured by the other gates.

Comment: *"This is my if/else if/ else statement"* - There are *many* conditional statements in this code.  What *specifically* isn't working?  *"The else statement at the end"* - `else` doesn't check a condition, it executes when no previous condition was met.  What condition did you expect to be met?  What were the values of the variables at that time?  Why did you expect the condition to be `true` with those values?

Comment: You need to use `&&` instead of nested `if` statements. Otherwise, if one of the outer `if` statements is true, it will skip the rest of the `else` branches.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: You *could* do this with `switch`, but I doubt it would be simpler. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Every test is about the value of `shirtWidth`. Not only would the code be simpler, but from a performance standpoint, it makes no sense to look up that value 100 times instead of once.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: You're assuming discrete values for `shirtWidth`. Also, from the OP's question, it would appear that `shirtWidth` *isn't* the only criterion, that one has to consider multiple criteria. (That said, I suspect the logic is flawed.)

Answer (score 4):

Consider this part from a logic perspective:

```
// Small Shirts
if(shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth < 20) {
        if(shirtLength >= 28 && shirtLength < 29)
        if(shirtSleeve >= 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38) {
            console.log("S");
        }
}
else // ...
```

So if `shirtWidth` matches that first condition, you branch into the body of the `if`. But if `shirtLength` or `shirtSleeve` don't match the conditions there, you don't do anything. At all. Because the `else` isn't connected to them. It's connected to the `if(shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth < 20)`.

Combine your conditions with `&&` and use only a single layer of `if`s:

```
// Small Shirts
if (shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth < 20 &&
    shirtLength >= 28 && shirtLength < 29 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38) {
    console.log("S");
}
// Medium Shirts
else // ...
```

---

Having said that, aside from syntax, I suspect the logic of the code isn't quite what you want. What if a `shirtWidth` is 19 but `shirtLength` is 30? None of your cases handles that.

Answer (score 1):

[T.J Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47579479/736893) is perfect (and should be accepted), but I might suggest separating your conditions to make it easier to read and manage:

```js
var shirtWidth = 18;
var shirtLength = 33;
var shirtSleeve = 8.63;

var isSmall = shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth < 20 && shirtLength >= 28 && shirtLength < 29 && shirtSleeve >= 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38;
var isMedium = shirtWidth >= 20 && shirtWidth < 22 && shirtLength >= 29 && shirtLength < 30 && shirtSleeve >= 8.38 && shirtSleeve < 8.63;
var isLarge = shirtWidth >= 22 && shirtWidth < 24 && shirtLength >= 30 && shirtLength < 31 && shirtSleeve >= 8.63 && shirtSleeve < 8.88;
var isXL = shirtWidth >= 22 && shirtWidth < 24 && shirtLength >= 31 && shirtLength < 33 && shirtSleeve >= 8.88 && shirtSleeve < 9.63;
var isXXL = shirtWidth >= 26 && shirtWidth < 28 && shirtLength >= 33 && shirtLength < 34 && shirtSleeve >= 9.63 && shirtSleeve < 10.13;
var is3XL = shirtWidth === 28 && shirtLength === 34 && shirtSleeve === 10.13;

if(isSmall) {
  console.log("S");
} else if(isMedium) {
  console.log("M");
} else if(isLarge) {
  console.log("L");
} else if(isXL) {
  console.log("XL");
} else if(isXXL) {
  console.log("2XL");
} else if(is3XL) {
  console.log("3XL");
} else {// Does not match any shirt sizes
    console.log("N/A");
}
```

Comment: Makes it clearer, although it does a fair bit of extra work. (Not that I imagine this is in a tight loop running hundreds of thousands of times...) I think I'd use `isSmall`, `isMedium`, etc. *functions*.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a `return` statement at each `console.log` statement or combine the `if` conditions using the `&&` operator.

```
var shirtWidth = 18;
var shirtLength = 33;
var shirtSleeve = 8.63;

// Small Shirts
if (shirtWidth >= 18 &&
    shirtWidth < 20 &&
    shirtLength >= 28 &&
    shirtLength < 29 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.13 &&
    shirtSleeve < 8.38) {
    console.log("S");
}
// Medium Shirts
else if (shirtWidth >= 20 &&
    shirtWidth < 22 &&
    shirtLength >= 29 &&
    shirtLength < 30 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.38 &&
    shirtSleeve < 8.63) {
    console.log("M");
}
// Large Shirts
else if (shirtWidth >= 22 &&
    shirtWidth < 24 &&
    shirtLength >= 30 &&
    shirtLength < 31 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.63 &&
    shirtSleeve < 8.88) {
    console.log("L");
}
// XL Shirts
else if (shirtWidth >= 24 &&
    shirtWidth < 26 &&
    shirtLength >= 31 &&
    shirtLength < 33 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.88 && shirtSleeve < 9.63) {
    console.log("XL");
}
// 2XL Shirts
else if (shirtWidth >= 26 &&
    shirtWidth < 28 &&
    shirtLength >= 33 &&
    shirtLength < 34 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 9.63 &&
    shirtSleeve < 10.13) {
    console.log("2XL");
}
// 3XL Shirts
else if (shirtWidth === 28 &&
    shirtLength === 34 &&
    shirtSleeve === 10.13) {
    console.log("3XL");

}
// Does not match any shirt sizes
else {
    console.log("N/A");
}
```

Not the best possible way to do this, but this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
var shirtWidth = 24;
var shirtLength = 28;
var shirtSleeve = 10;

// Small Shirts
if(shirtWidth >= 18 && shirtWidth < 20 &&
    shirtLength >= 28 && shirtLength < 29 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.13 && shirtSleeve < 8.38) {
        console.log("S");
    }
// Medium Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 20 && shirtWidth < 22 &&
    shirtLength >= 29 && shirtLength < 30 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.38 && shirtSleeve < 8.63) {
        console.log("M");
    }
// Large Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 22 && shirtWidth < 24 &&
    shirtLength >= 30 && shirtLength < 31 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.63 && shirtSleeve < 8.88) {
        console.log("L");
    }
// XL Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 24 && shirtWidth < 26 &&
    shirtLength >= 31 && shirtLength < 33 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 8.88 && shirtSleeve < 9.63) {
        console.log("XL");
    }
// 2XL Shirts
else if(shirtWidth >= 26 && shirtWidth < 28 &&
    shirtLength >= 33 && shirtLength < 34 &&
    shirtSleeve >= 9.63 && shirtSleeve < 10.13) {
        console.log("2XL");
    }
// 3XL Shirts
else if(shirtWidth === 28 &&
    shirtLength === 34 &&
    shirtSleeve === 10.13) {
        console.log("3XL");
    }
// Does not match any shirt sizes
else {
    console.log("N/A");
}
```